# Obtain a list of month and records from the current date(month) in two different years

Tags: mysql, sql, date, mysql-workbench

I have such a set of records in a table in a mysql database;

```
Date                | Number_of_leaves
10th-December-2015  |   10 leaves 
6th-August-2015     | 10 leaves
15th-September-2015 |  14 leaves
15th-January-2016:  |   100 leaves
7th-November-2015:  |  4 leaves
9th-October -2015:  |  200 leaves
```

How can i return a list months and their records for just the past 4 months from Jan-2016 backwards? In other words, i need a result for the past 4 months including the current one like this:

```
January 2016  |  100 leaves
December 2015 | 10 leaves
November 2015 | 4 leaves
October 2015  |  200 leaves
```

The above is the kind of result which shows the month and the corresponding year with the number of leaves collected in that month and corresponding year

Comment: is that actually your column, a string for Date?

Comment: also, how do you get 5 for Jan, cuz it is the last one for Jan? Also why are your dates in different formats?

Comment: thats just a snapshot of what i have as long as you understand it. Jan represents january  -- what is so hard to understand. I am not intrested in the different formats of the dates but rather , how do we subtract dates to obtain months if the dates lie in two different years?

Comment: the Dates belong to the Date column. the number of Leaves are in the numbers(INT) column but what i have written up there is just to give you an idea of what kind of records i have. are you goin to ask me why i have a full colon in a database too? Please Focus on the question and try to understand not Pick out mispellings or 'little' specks like that!

Comment: I am trying to determine if certain functions need to be run based on what you are showing. Been around the block

Comment: Well I have spent 10 min trying to get you a solution, not nit pick. I am happy to move on to another question. So why is January 5 the answer. Because your question does not explain that. And someone, like myself, has to deliver it to you

Comment: why is January 5 my answer; because 5 leaves were picked in January 2016, this is quite clearly shown.

Comment: how about the 15. That is clearly shown too.

Comment: January 2016: 5 leaves
December 2015: 10 leaves
November 2015: 4 leaves
October 2015: 200 leaves

Comment: It's your data. You hand typed it (colons and all !)

Comment: meaning 5 leaves were picked in January 2016. 10 leaves in November 2015; 4 leaves were picked in October 2015.... e.t.c; this is an example of an answer i need - i havent gotten the correct answer which is why is posted the question in the first place!

Comment: its 15 January 2016: 5 leaves --> 5 leaves were picked on 15th January 2016!

Comment: `12th-Jan-2016: 15 leaves` it's your data bro

Comment: now how do we handle it

Comment: 15th January 2016 -- i missed the "th" on the 15....but this is not the issue. Forget what i typed or didnot: the issue is How can we subtract 4 months from that date and be able to return the correct number of months in the past year.... Can you help on this ??

Comment: I can help you. It does matter what you typed because you have 2 rows for Jan 2016 and I am trying to follow your directions. So why don't you clean up the question with an [edit] so someone can read it and answer it and not read your mind. I will be back in a bit

Comment: Well, then delete the row: 12th-Jan-2016: 15 leaves ---i don't need it! the question is quite clear, how do we subtract the 4 months from this date and filter the results??  Like i said, i dont have the correct result with me, but i gave you an idea of what i would love to see.

Comment: Thanks for the notice: I have edited the table and the question; i hope it looks clear now

Comment: Now, How we solve the main problem?

Answer (score 1):

### Schema

```
create table xyz
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    theDate date not null,
    leaves int not null
);

-- truncate table xyz;
insert xyz(theDate,leaves) values
('2016-04-10',444510), 
('2016-02-10',55510), 
('2015-12-10',10), 
('2015-08-06',10),
('2015-09-15',14),
('2016-01-15',100),
('2015-11-07',4), 
('2015-10-09',200);
```

### Query 1

```
select month(theDate) as m,
year(theDate) as y,
sum(leaves) as leaves
from xyz
where theDate<='2016-02-01'
group by month(theDate),year(theDate)
order by theDate desc
limit 4;
```

or

### Query 2

```
select concat(monthname(theDate),' ',year(theDate)) as 'Month/Year', 
sum(leaves) as leaves 
from xyz 
where theDate<='2016-02-01' 
group by month(theDate),year(theDate) 
order by theDate desc 
limit 4;

+---------------+--------+
| Month/Year    | leaves |
+---------------+--------+
| January 2016  |    100 |
| December 2015 |     10 |
| November 2015 |      4 |
| October 2015  |    200 |
+---------------+--------+
```

Comment: Fantastic, Query 2! Thanks a bunch Drew.

Answer (score 0):

`op` is your table name first use `str_to_date` for convert string to date format .we use `if` because your date format is different

```
select * FROM (
SELECT *,
IFNULL(
    IFNULL(
    str_to_date(Date,'%D-%b-%Y'),str_to_date(Date,'%d-%M-%Y')) ,
    str_to_date(Date,'%D-%M-%Y')
    )    
f_date     
FROM `op` 
order by number_of_leaves DESC,f_date ASC    
) tab
group by month(tab.f_date) LIMIT 5
```